# HTTP 401 Basic Authentication error accessing Magento 2 Rest API

Tags: rest, magento, http-status-code-401

I am attempting to use the Rest API in Magento 2.  I have a piece of PHP that uses cURL to first get an admin token for my Magento user, then use the token to return a piece of Magento data (in this example a list of product types).  The first part returns a token with no problems, but the second part comes back with an HTTP 401 Basic Authentication error.

My code is:

```
<?php

// Get handle for token retrieval
$userData = array("username" => "user", "password" => "password!");
$ch = curl_init("https://my.magento/rest/V1/integration/admin/token/");

// Set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('/tmp/curl.log', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// Get token
$token = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Token returned: " . $token . "<BR><BR>";

// Display log
rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information 1:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";

echo "About to get product<BR>";

// Get handle for product types
$ch = curl_init("https://my.magento/rest/V1/products/types/");

// Set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('/tmp/curl.log', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// Get types
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Result: " . $result . "<BR>"; 

// Display log
rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "<BR>Verbose information 2:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";

?>
```

And the browser output is:

```
Tokenreturned: "t8iskt68xlo5frf9hhtc1lk8wmqzbzx8"

Verbose information 1: 
* About to connect() to my.magento port 443 (#2)
*   Trying 104.25.128.20...
* Connected to mymagento (nn.nn.nn.nn) port 443 (#2)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*     subject: CN=ssl379212.cloudflaressl.com,OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain,OU=Domain Control Validated
*     start date: Oct 26 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*     expire date: May 04 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*     common name: ssl379212.cloudflaressl.com
*     issuer: CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
> POST /rest/V1/integration/admin/token/ HTTP/1.1
Host: sand2.firetoys.co.uk
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48

* upload completely sent off: 48 out of 48 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 12:50:01 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 34
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d69af7d1f0a1205231a8867c1f45875621540990201; expires=Thu, 31-Oct-19 12:50:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.my.magento; HttpOnly
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9p378rsfito8gfocnrufucssh6; expires=Wed, 31-Oct-2018 13:50:01 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=sand2.firetoys.co.uk; secure; HttpOnly
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 47263eb629ea0ce9-LHR
< 
* Connection #2 to host my.magento left intact
About to get product
Result: 

Verbose information 2: 
* About to connect() to my.magento port 443 (#3)
*   Trying nn.nn.nn.nn...
* Connected to my.magento (nn.nn.nn.nn) port 443 (#3)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*     subject: CN=ssl379212.cloudflaressl.com,OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain,OU=Domain Control Validated
*     start date: Oct 26 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*     expire date: May 04 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*     common name: ssl379212.cloudflaressl.com
*     issuer: CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
> GET /rest/V1/products/types/ HTTP/1.1
Host: sand2.firetoys.co.uk
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer t8iskt68xlo5frf9hhtc1lk8wmqzbzx8

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 12:50:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d38c9e4bc3019d9ac55c7f68f5c5ca1161540990201; expires=Thu, 31-Oct-19 12:50:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.my.magento; HttpOnly
< X-Varnish: 7995397
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 47263eb70f5b3512-LHR
< 
* Connection #3 to host my.magento left intact
```

When I try just browsing directly to https://my.magento/rest/V1/products/types/ I get a Magento error back saying I am not authorised for the Products resource, which I would expect as I am sending no token or login credentials, but at least it is getting through to Magento.

Any ideas??

I should add that the server is set for Basic authentication, and if I replace the Bearer auth with the necessary Basic auth in the header for the GET, it returns the Magento message about not having access to the resource, which is fair enough.  So I guess there are two questions:

1. How can I get past the basic authentication and still include the bearer authentication in my GET request, given that you can't put two authentications into the header?
2. Why does the initial POST to get the token work without any basic auth??

Answer (score 0):

> "How can I get past the basic authentication and still include the bearer authentication in my GET request, given that you can't put two authentications into the header?"

Disable auth for /index.php/rest location (in webserver)

> "Why does the initial POST to get the token work without any basic auth??"

If the POST location is protected then you should get a 401 response.
Did you put the username and password on url on post request? http://user:pass@my.magento/rest/V1/

By the way, putting user:pass@my.magento into URL, will be translated into Authorization: User .

But you also set Authorization: Bearer t8iskt68xlo5frf9hhtc1lk8wmqzbzx8 which will overwrite the http authentification Authorization.